# Paypal Recurring Express Checkout

Tags: paypal

I have a website for Recurring payment with Express Checkout. I would like to know about the paypal merchant account type .Do a personal account is enough for it?

Fida

Answer (score 1):

I believe a personal account is sufficient. I think paypal call it Web Payments Standard Account

These should help

1. https://www.paypal-business.co.uk/accept-online-payments-with-paypal/index.htm
2. [PP_WebsitePaymentsStandard_IntegrationGuide.pdf](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_WebsitePaymentsStandard_IntegrationGuide.pdf)

Comment: Yes, it is sufficient. You need Website Payments Pro only for recurring payments and/or when you have the checkout process on right your page (i.e. no redirect to paypal).